# How to log in foreachRDD in streaming application?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

we are working on a application consuming kafka messages using spark streaming ..running on a hadoop/yarn spark cluster ....i have log4j properties confiured both on driver and the worker's ...but i still don't see the log messages inside the foreachRDD ..i do see the "start for each rdd" and "end of for each rdd"

```
val broadcaseLme=sc.broadcast(lme)
logInfo("start for each rdd: ")
val lines: DStream[MetricTypes.InputStreamType] = myConsumer.createDefaultStream()  
             lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {
            if ((rdd != null) && (rdd.count() > 0) && (!rdd.isEmpty()) ) {
              **logInfo("filteredLines: " + rdd.count())**
              **logInfo("start loop")**
              rdd.foreach{x => 
                 val lme = broadcastLme.value    
                 lme.aParser(x).get
                  }
              logInfo("end loop")
            }   })

         logInfo("end of for each rdd ")

              lines.print(10)
```

I'm running the application on the cluster using this

```
spark-submit --verbose --class DevMain --master yarn-cluster --deploy-mode cluster --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.p‌​roperties" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j‌​.properties" --files "hdfs://hdfs-name-node:8020/user/hadoopuser/log4j.properties‌​" hdfs://hdfs-name-node:8020/user/hadoopuser/streaming_2.10-1.‌​0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar hdfs://hdfs-name-node:8020/user/hadoopuser/enriched.properti‌​es
```

I'm new to spark could some one please help why i'm not seeing the log messages inside the foreachrdd this is the log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, rolling

log4j.appender.rolling=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rolling.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rolling.layout.conversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
log4j.appender.rolling.maxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.rolling.maxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.rolling.file=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/titanium-spark-enriched.log
#log4j.appender.rolling.encoding=URF-8

log4j.logger.org.apache,spark=WARN
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN

log4j.logger.com.x1.projectname=INFO

#log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
#log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
#log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
#log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty=WARN
#log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
#log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
#log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO

# SPARK-9183: Settings to avoid annoying messages when looking up nonexistent UDFs in SparkSQL with Hive support
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler=FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry=ERROR

#log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=./logs/spark/enriched.log
#log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
#log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n


#log4j.rootLogger=INFO, RollingAppender, console
```

Comment: Deploy mode is cluster, so driver's logs will be on one of cluster nodes. Have you checked node's logs?

Comment: I'm using yarn for aggregating the logs i don't see the log messages inside foreachRdd

Comment: How did you create myConsumer? What about lines DStream?  Show the code that you foreach later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the Spark Streaming application seems to be with a missing `start` after you've built your streaming computation, i.e.

```
ssc.start()
```

Quoting the [scaladoc of StreamingContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext):

> After creating and transforming DStreams, the streaming computation can be started and stopped using `context.start()` and `context.stop()`, respectively.
>
> `context.awaitTermination()` allows the current thread to wait for the termination of the context by `stop()` or by an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jacek ...but i do have ssc.start without which i wouldn't get the log message's i'm already getting.......

Comment: So the only reason I can now come up with why you don't get the starred logs is the guard condition `(rdd != null) && (rdd.count() > 0) && (!rdd.isEmpty()` Why do you have it?

Comment: That's to make sure i don't get null or empty rdd ...because ...sometimes we do get empty batches when streaming . please correct me if i'm not right in my assumption